# Getting search field to filter results in Angular, problems Gulp / ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

## Problem

I have an input field that I want readers to be able to search businesses, which have been put onto the page using Angular's `ng-repeat.` Right now, when I type into the search field, it doesn't filter any of them.

## Where the problem could be

Wondering if it's a problem with the gulpfile.js and how it's compiling my build folder. Other possibilities include incorrect using of the directive `ng-model` or if my `ng-controller="MainCtrl"` is in the wrong place?

Currently I'm using Foundation for Apps, which include Angular views and routing. I've included a link to my Github and code samples below.

## Edit #1:

**Putting the `ng-controller="MainCtrl"` in the header does not seem to work, instead the businesses do not show up when compiled.**

## Github: https://github.com/onlyandrewn/angular

### gulpfile.js

```
// FOUNDATION FOR APPS TEMPLATE GULPFILE
// -------------------------------------
// This file processes all of the assets in the "client" folder, combines them with the Foundation for Apps assets, and outputs the finished files in the "build" folder as a finished app.

// 1. LIBRARIES
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

var $        = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var argv     = require('yargs').argv;
var gulp     = require('gulp');
var rimraf   = require('rimraf');
var router   = require('front-router');
var sequence = require('run-sequence');

// Check for --production flag
var isProduction = !!(argv.production);

// 2. FILE PATHS
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

var paths = {
  assets: [
    './client/**/*.*',
    '!./client/templates/**/*.*',
    '!./client/assets/{scss,js}/**/*.*'
  ],
  // Sass will check these folders for files when you use @import.
  sass: [
    'client/assets/scss',
    'bower_components/foundation-apps/scss'
  ],
  // These files include Foundation for Apps and its dependencies
  foundationJS: [
    'bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js',
    'bower_components/viewport-units-buggyfill/viewport-units-buggyfill.js',
    'bower_components/tether/tether.js',
    'bower_components/hammerjs/hammer.js',
    'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
    'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
    'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
    'bower_components/foundation-apps/js/vendor/**/*.js',
    'bower_components/foundation-apps/js/angular/**/*.js',
    '!bower_components/foundation-apps/js/angular/app.js'
  ],
  // These files are for your app's JavaScript
  appJS: [
    'client/assets/js/*.js'
    // 'client/assets/js/app.js'
  ]
}

// 3. TASKS
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

// Cleans the build directory
gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
  rimraf('./build', cb);
});

// Copies everything in the client folder except templates, Sass, and JS
gulp.task('copy', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.assets, {
    base: './client/'
  })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'))
  ;
});

// Copies your app's page templates and generates URLs for them
gulp.task('copy:templates', function() {
  return gulp.src('./client/templates/**/*.html')
    .pipe(router({
      path: 'build/assets/js/routes.js',
      root: 'client'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/templates'))
  ;
});

// Compiles the Foundation for Apps directive partials into a single JavaScript file
gulp.task('copy:foundation', function(cb) {
  gulp.src('bower_components/foundation-apps/js/angular/components/**/*.html')
    .pipe($.ngHtml2js({
      prefix: 'components/',
      moduleName: 'foundation',
      declareModule: false
    }))
    .pipe($.uglify())
    .pipe($.concat('templates.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/assets/js'))
  ;

  // Iconic SVG icons
  gulp.src('./bower_components/foundation-apps/iconic/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/assets/img/iconic/'))
  ;

  cb();
});

// Compiles Sass
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('client/assets/scss/app.scss')
    .pipe($.sass({
      includePaths: paths.sass,
      outputStyle: (isProduction ? 'compressed' : 'nested'),
      errLogToConsole: true
    }))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie 10']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/assets/css/'))
  ;
});

// Compiles and copies the Foundation for Apps JavaScript, as well as your app's custom JS
gulp.task('uglify', ['uglify:foundation', 'uglify:app'])

gulp.task('uglify:foundation', function(cb) {
  var uglify = $.if(isProduction, $.uglify()
    .on('error', function (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }));

  return gulp.src(paths.foundationJS)
    .pipe(uglify)
    .pipe($.concat('foundation.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/assets/js/'))
  ;
});

gulp.task('uglify:app', function() {
  var uglify = $.if(isProduction, $.uglify()
    .on('error', function (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }));

  return gulp.src(paths.appJS)
    .pipe(uglify)
    .pipe($.concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/assets/js/'))
  ;
});

// Starts a test server, which you can view at http://localhost:8080
gulp.task('server', ['build'], function() {
  gulp.src('./build')
    .pipe($.webserver({
      port: 8080,
      host: 'localhost',
      fallback: 'index.html',
      livereload: true,
      open: true
    }))
  ;
});

// Builds your entire app once, without starting a server
gulp.task('build', function(cb) {
  sequence('clean', ['copy', 'copy:foundation', 'sass', 'uglify'], 'copy:templates', cb);
});

// Default task: builds your app, starts a server, and recompiles assets when they change
gulp.task('default', ['server'], function () {
  // Watch Sass
  gulp.watch(['./client/assets/scss/**/*', './scss/**/*'], ['sass']);

  // Watch JavaScript
  gulp.watch(['./client/assets/js/**/*', './js/**/*'], ['uglify:app']);

  // Watch static files
  gulp.watch(['./client/**/*.*', '!./client/templates/**/*.*', '!./client/assets/{scss,js}/**/*.*'], ['copy']);

  // Watch app templates
  gulp.watch(['./client/templates/**/*.html'], ['copy:templates']);
});
```

### home.html (Template containing ng-model / ng-controller)

```
---
name: home
url: /
---

<header>
    <p class="sponsored">Sponsored by </p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x30" class="sponsors" alt="">
    <h1>Business Directory</h1>
    <div class="find">
        <label for="looking">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </label>
        <input type="search" placeholder="What are you looking for?" ng-model="query">
        <input type="submit">

    </div><!-- /.find -->
    <ul>
        <li class="popular">Popular searches:</li>
        <li>tk-category <span>|</li>
        <li>tk-category <span>|</span></li>
        <li>tk-category <span>|</span></li>
        <li>tk-category <span>|</span></li>
        <li>tk-category </li>
    </ul>
</header>

<div class="businesses">
    <p class="number">tk-number of businesses</p><button class="filter button">Filter by <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></button>
    <div class="options">
        <div class="cat">
            <div class="categories">
                <div class="group">
                    <p class="name">Grade Level</p>
                    <div class="check">
                        <input type="radio" name=""><p>Auto</p>
                        <input type="checkbox" name=""><p>Restaurant</p>
                        <input type="checkbox" name=""><p>Other</p>
                    </div><!-- /.check -->
                </div><!-- /.group -->

                <div class="group">
                    <p class="name">School Type</p>
                    <div class="check">
                        <input type="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox">
                    </div><!-- /.check -->
                </div><!-- /.group -->
            </div><!-- /.categories -->
        </div><!-- /.cat -->
    </div><!-- /.options -->
</div><!-- /.businesses -->

<div class="all" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="business large-4.columns" data-ng-repeat="business in businesses | filter:query" >
        <div class="overlay">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="storefront" alt="">
        </div><!-- /.overlay -->
        <div class="info">
            <p class="name">{{business.name}}</p>
            <p class="description">{{business.description}}</p>
            <p class="address">{{business.address}}</p>
            <a href="" class="website">{{business.website}}</a>
        </div><!-- /.info -->
    </div>
</div>

<footer>
    <p>Back to top</p>
</footer>

<!-- <div class="buttons">
    <button class="alp">Alphabetically</button>
    <button class="exp">Expanded</button>
    <button class="con">Condensed</button>
</div> -->

<!-- <div class="grid-container"> -->
<!-- </div> -->
```

### index.html (Has the  tag with ng-app="application")

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="application">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Brandon Sun Business Directory</title>
    <link href="/assets/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grid-frame vertical">
      <div class="grid-content shrink" style="padding: 0;">
        <div class="primary condense menu-bar">
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/80x45" class="bdnsun" alt="">
          <div class="social">
            <a href="" class="click"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="" class="click"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
          </div><!-- /.social -->
        </div><!-- /.logo -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div ui-view class="grid-content">
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/templates.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/2.2.0/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### scripts.js

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.businesses = [
  {
   id: 0,
   name: "Andrew Nguyen",
   description: "I'm a web developer",
   address: "322 11th Street, Brandon, MB",
   website: "http://andrewnguyen.ca"
 },
 {
   id: 1,
   name: "Mary Yacoubian",
   description: "I'm a dental hygenist",
   address: "18 Wishford Drive",
   website: "http://quitecontrary.com"
 },
 {
   id: 2,
   name: "John Axon",
   description: "I'm a jack of all trades",
   address: "1101 Mississauga Rd.",
   website: "http://johnaxon.com"
 }
 ]
});
```

### app.js

```
'use strict';

  var myApp = angular.module('application', [
    'ui.router',
    'ngAnimate',

    //foundation
    'foundation',
    'foundation.dynamicRouting',
    'foundation.dynamicRouting.animations'
  ])
    .config(config)
    .run(run)
  ;

  config.$inject = ['$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider'];

  function config($urlProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlProvider.otherwise('/');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled:false,
      requireBase: false
    });

    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
  }

  function run() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
  }
```

Comment: its because the query variable is outside of MainCtrl

Comment: you fixed it, i cloned your project & it works fine for me.